# Scion of the Ur-Dragon multiple transformation

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Consider this situation: I use the ability of [Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon) and put it in the stack. My opponent play [Rending Volley](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rending%20Volley) in response targeting Scion of the Ur-Dragon. In response I use it's ability again and put it in the top of the stack. First the dragon's ability resolves and I can choose any dragon that is not blue or white to avoid the volley(lets say [Shivan Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shivan%20Dragon)). Then the volley resolves and it does not do anything because it has an invalid target. What happens next? The last ability in the stack says that Scion of the Ur-Dragon turn into a copy of a dragon, but it's name has changed to Shivan Dragon. Can I transform it again anyways with the last ability in the stack (if my first intention was to transform it in [Oros, the Avenger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oros%2C%20the%20Avenger) for example?

Comment: Minor note: the Rending Volley does not resolve; it is actually countered by the rules because it no longer has a valid target.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You are right, nice catch.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That is backwards. Per 608, after the players pass priority, the top spell or ability on the stack will resolve. As it is resolving, it will check if the target is still legal, per 608.2b; since "Shivan Dragon" isn't a legal target, Rending Volley is countered. The question posits the chain of events correctly.

Comment: Yes, you can also say "it starts to resolve and then is countered by the rules". The distinction I was making was between "the spell was countered *instead of* doing anything", as in this case, and "the spell resolved, but did not affect its targets", like if you cast Aerial Predation targeting Avacyn, Angel of Hope. Often, the word "resolves" is used to mean "you follow the instructions on the card" rather than "you follow the steps in rule 608"

Comment: Admittedly, I suffer for an addiction to precision.

Comment: It isn't uncommon to activate Scion multiple times (while holding priority) in order to take advantage of abilities on different dragons. (e.g., transforming into Moltensteel Dragon, pumping, then transforming into Atarka, World Render.)

Comment: @HaoYe When you transform it into Atarka, World Render the pumping is not lost?

Comment: @RenatoSanhueza The buff stays. You can see [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21065/snakeform-and-buff-ineractions/21066#21066) for more info on how this works.

Comment: @HaoYe What happens if I give "haste" to Scion and then I use the ability to transform? Does the transformation override the "haste"?

Comment: @RenatoSanhueza - Usually such effects are continuous and last as long as the object doesn't leave the battlefield, but you should ask a new question, because it would depend on how the creature gains "haste".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works. The following will explain the mechanics that you're asking about, passing over the parts you've identified.

[Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon), after the *second* activation of it's ability resolves, will be a copy of Shivan Dragon. Now, the *First* ability will try to resolve, and looks for the [Scion of Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20Ur-Dragon), finding it as [Shivan Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shivan%20Dragon).

This is because of rules 109.1, 109.3, 201.4, and 201.5.

> 109.1. An object is an ability on the stack, a card, a copy of a card, a token, a spell, a permanent, or an emblem.

Your [Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon), now a [Shivan Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shivan%20Dragon), is an object.

> 109.3. An object’s characteristics are name, mana cost, color, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, abilities, power, toughness, loyalty, hand modifier, and life modifier. Objects can have some or all of these  characteristics. Any other information about an object isn’t a characteristic. For example, characteristics don’t include whether a permanent is tapped, a spell’s target, an object’s owner or controller, what an Aura enchants, and so on.

Of the multiple Characteristics the object has, we care about its name: [Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon).

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

Specifically, we care about its name at the time the abilities of interest are activated, because that ability refers to it by name.

> 201.5. If an ability of an object uses a phrase such as “this [something]” to identify an object, where [something] is a characteristic, it is referring to that particular object, even if it isn’t the appropriate characteristic at the time.

When the ability is activated and placed on the stack, though it said [Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon) at the time, it is referring to that card. Even after the effect of the *second* ability activation copies the Characteristics of [Shivan Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shivan%20Dragon), the ability on the stack still point at that card.